# Two plugins sharing the same custom post type registration

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I have two plugins Plugin A and Plugin B registering the same post type exp, aws_employee. Each plugin offers different functionality but the post type type they share is exactly the same.

If I activate plugin A first and then Plugin B, Plugin B does not activate since Plugin B tries to register the same post type.

I'd like Plugin B to check if aws_employee type registered then if it is to reuse it. Please note that Plugin B may register other post types. How can I do that?

Conceptual Model:
Plugin A 
- Post type A
- Post type B
- Post type C (shared) 
   - Custom Taxonomy A
   - Custom Taxonomy B
   - Custom Taxonomy C(shared)
Plugin B 
- Post type C (shared) 
   - Custom Taxonomy C(shared)
   - Custom Taxonomy D
   - Custom Taxonomy E
- Post type D 
- Post type E

Update on July 5th:
Plugin A and Plugin B offer distinctively different functionality however they share data(post type). A segment (UserGroup A) of users targeted for Plugin A does not want to use/pay/see/install Plugin B. Another segment(UserGroup B) wants to use Plugin A and Plugin B in the same installation. The preferred solution must accommodate both User Group A and B.

Comment: I cannot see why you are doing this. Do not split your functionalty between two plugins.

Comment: I tend to agree with @PieterGoosen. Can you explain your useage in more detail?

Comment: Added more explanation on July 5th.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`get_post_types`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) function to fetch and search through the registered post types up to that point (the `init` hook where you would normally register the custom post type). You can possibly use a later hook like `wp_loaded` to do this check before trying to register the post type in case some other (not related to any of yours) plugin might have registered it already.